# Kivy canvas - fast drawing - polylines

Tags: android, python, canvas, drawing, kivy

Tell me please, if drawing in Kivy Canvas fast, I get very acute, 
polylines figure, but if drawing very slow, then I get smooth lines.

```
    ...

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
            return True
        print(touch.x, touch.y)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(*get_color_from_hex('#0080FF80'))
            Line(circle=(touch.x, touch.y, 2), width=2)
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=2)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):                               
        if 'current_line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud['current_line'].points += (touch.x, touch.y)
    ...
```

This is my example:

[image: this is my example!]

Who knows how could I fixed it ?
Could I drawing fast and smooth in Kivy ?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why the lines dont look smooth when you draw fast in kivy, can you please test it on a different devices.

Comment: of course i tested on many different devices, and  maybe I'm a little bit exaggerating, but realy picture is not more better - 


[another pic link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n3jqw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tested your code and couldn't produce the issue you are having. I mean it doesn't matter if I draw fast or slow in Kivy. Half of these 'e's I drew fast and half slow but no difference in output. I suggest you try https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html . If this example's drawing output is acute while drawing fast, then probably there is something wrong with your environment because it works well in mine. elif it's smooth in fast drawing, then your project in hand must be having issues.

[image]

Comment: on PC everything is  great, but let's try to test it on Android platform.
You may check it in my App - [SpringPaint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ek.myspaint)